# Spring Rest Controller + jquery ajax + киррилица

Tags: ajax, spring, rest, controller

Здравствуйте. Сегодня столкнулся с проблемой. Почему на сервере в json вместо русских символов какая-то каша? Буду чрезвычайно благодарен за помощь. На стороне клиента через ajax отправляется json array, например

```
[ {name: "ФИО", value: "Имя Отчество"}, 
   {name: "Email", value: "email@mail.com"}
]
```

На  сервер приходит

```
[{"name":"Ð¢ÐµÐ»ÐµÑÐ¾Ð½","value":"ÐÐ¼Ñ ÐÑÑÐµÑÑÐ²Ð¾"},
 {"name":"Email","value":"email@mail.com"}
]
```

Вид ajax запроса :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://localhost:8443/sendfieldstoms",
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify(data_for_send),
  success: console.log(data)
});
```

использую простейший контроллер

```
@RestController
public class AnotherService  {

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendfieldstoms", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void sendfieldstoms(@RequestBody String req)throws Exception{
        System.out.println(req);
    }
}
```

Comment: Предположу, что у тебя разная кодировка на сервере и на клиенте. Посмотри можно ли заставить его отсылать данные в конкретной кодировке (не знаю можно ли в Spring). И проверь данные в каких кодировках у тя находятся на сервере, на клиенте и т.д. (если еще что-то используешь - бд например)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в самом spring, который по умолчанию использует ISO-8859-1. Добавил в web.xml фильтр:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```